# Keep table header from hiding on search

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the table sort on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) as a base, how can I keep my table header from disappearing on searching the table?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search-attorneys').on('keyup', function(){
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = $("#search-attorneys");
    filter = $("#search-attorneys").val().toUpperCase();
    table = $("#attorneys");
    tr = $("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      var found = false;
      for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        td = tds[j];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/1zg85s9s/6/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do change in first for loop:-

```
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) { // not start with 0 start with 1.
```

Means leave table `<thead><tr>` and then start searching in rest `<tr>`.

Note:- check it and if you are facing any problem. I will create an example for you.

Comment: Mat glad to help you.:):):)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by putting the rows in a tbody, and changing the variabl;e `tr` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search-attorneys').on('keyup', function(){
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = $("#search-attorneys");
    filter = $("#search-attorneys").val().toUpperCase();
    table = $("#attorneys");
    tr = $("tbody tr"); // CHANGED
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      var found = false;
      for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        td = tds[j];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-attorneys" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">


<table id="attorneys">
  <thead class="cf">
          <tr>
            <th class="numeric">attorney</th>
            <th class="numeric">location</th>
            <th class="numeric">practice area</th>
            <th class="numeric">email</th>
            <th class="numeric">phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
    <td data-title="location">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```